# Actionscript 3: How can I get the symbol name, and not the instance name

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

A silly question, but I spent an hour trying to find it: 
I created a symbol, and named it symbol_a. How can I get this symbol name from an instance?
If I use

myInstance.name

I  get the instance name and not the symbol name......

Thanks in advance,

Edward

Answer (score 4):

This will return the name of the "symbol" (String).

```
getQualifiedClassName(yourSymbolInstance);`
```

This will give you the Class Object of your instance.

```
var c:Class=yourSymbolInstance.constructor;
addChild(new c());
```

If you don't export your symbol, the symbol name will be MovieClip.

Comment: Yes this works as long as you export the symbol for ActionScript as you are extending the MovieClip class to a new class that you specify which defaults to the name of the symbol. The name of the symbol itself is a Flash thing used to organise the library. It has no relation to ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to get a symbol name using AS3.

Btw. why do you need it really?

Comment: Hi, I need it because I am creating a map with 20 areas (thus 20 symbols) in it. These areas change in color/function during the timeline, about 30 different dates. But with my customer Stupid as I was, creating those 30 different dates, I forgot to name them in the beginning. And I created also some comments at that time, so I couldn't rely on the instance names (instance1, instance2, instance3 etc). So I thought, well, I don't know the name, but I do know the symbol which I used......